# Updating multiple rows in datagridview all the same

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

i can only update 1 row but when two or multiple row when i update it all the values are the same
i don't know what is the error i put the sqlcommand inside the loop

```
       string date = dt_date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POSdb"].ConnectionString);

        string strQry = "UPDATE CounterChecking " +
        "SET part_no = @c0,po_no = @po_no,invoice = @invoice,part_name = @c1," +
        "date = @date,color = @c2,qty_ordered = @c3,qty_for_delivery = @c4,qty_recieved = @c5," +
        "variance = @c6,unit_price = @c7, total = @c8, remarks = @c9 " +
        "WHERE po_no= '" + cb_po_search.Text + "'";

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

            if (!row.IsNewRow)
            {
                sc.Open();
                    SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strQry, sc);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c0", row.Cells[0].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@po_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_ponumber2.Text;
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_invoice2.Text;
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", row.Cells[1].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", row.Cells[2].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", row.Cells[3].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", row.Cells[4].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", row.Cells[5].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", row.Cells[6].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c7", row.Cells[7].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c8", row.Cells[8].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c9", row.Cells[9].Value);
                    scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    scmd.Dispose();
                    sc.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated!");}
            sc.Close();
        }
```

no error but it gives me all the same data every row

Comment: it looks like you are updating same row(s) inside loop, your WHERE condition is fixed: "WHERE po_no= '" + cb_po_search.Text + "'";

Comment: i can add more value in data grid in one po means 1:*

Comment: In that case You also need another unique column in table CounterChecking then, what is the PK there? Add it to WHERE clause as well.

Comment: no PK over there my PK is counter_id just increment

Comment: change your WHERE clause to "WHERE po_no = @po_no AND counter_id = @counter_id". add both of these parameters inside the loop. counter_id column need to be bound to datagridview, if you dont need to display make it hidden.

Comment: what if i had a search box what do i put in @po_no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `SqlCommand` inside the loop and dispose the object once the command is executed. Try to use `try catch finally` block inside finally dispose the command object.

```
SqlCommand scmd;
do
    {
      scmd = new SqlCommand(strQry, sc);
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c0", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[0].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.Add("@po_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_ponumber2.Text;
      scmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_invoice2.Text;
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[1].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[2].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[3].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[4].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[5].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[6].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c7", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[7].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c8", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[8].Value);
      scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c9", dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[9].Value);
      counter++;
      scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      scmd.Dispose();
      MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated!");
   } while (counter < dataGridView1.Rows.Count);
```

Comment: i got this error the parameterized query'(@c0)' nvarchar(4000)

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate the command for every iteration. If you move `SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strQry, sc);` inside your do loop, you should be fine. But a better option would be to wrap it in a `using` clause like so and use a `foreach` to go through the `dataGridView1.Rows` collection:

```
        foreach(var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strQry, sc))
            {
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c0", row.Cells[0].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.Add("@po_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_ponumber2.Text;
                scmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_invoice2.Text;
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", row.Cells[1].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", row.Cells[2].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", row.Cells[3].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", row.Cells[4].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", row.Cells[5].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", row.Cells[6].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c7", row.Cells[7].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c8", row.Cells[8].Value);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c9", row.Cells[9].Value);
                scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated!");
            }
        }
```

The benefit of the `using` clause is that it will automatically call the `Dispose()` method on the object prior to exiting the clause.

Comment: this line is invalid foreach(dataGridView1.Rows as row)

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry, been working in PHP and had it in that syntax.